# WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot get automation extension from unknown error using Selenium ChromeDriver and Chrome through Python

Tags: python, macos, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

Pretty straightforward. On a Mac, using chromedriver in python. Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
EXE_PATH = r'chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=EXE_PATH)
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
driver.get('file:///index.html')
```

But it always crashes on the line:

```
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
```

The error it gives:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: 
cannot get automation extension
from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.80)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461585 (0be2cd95f834e9ee7c46bcc7cf405b483f5ae83b),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64)
```

As you can see my chrome version is 75.0.3770.80 and my chromedriver version is 2.29.461585. I believe these versions should work together. Is this a version mismatch issue or something else?

Comment: `chromedriver` changed their versioning scheme/number to match chrome's, so you want https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=75.0.3770.8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: 
cannot get automation extension
from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.29*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.29*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.29/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v56-58**

- You are using *chrome=75.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v75.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/75.0.3770.8/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v75**

So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver v2.29* and the *Chrome Browser v75.0*

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to [**ChromeDriver v2.75**](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=75.0.3770.8/) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v75*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.75 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/75.0.3770.8/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.

Comment: Thanks, seems like you know what you’re talking about so I have accepted the answer before being able to try and see if it works. I have full confidence in your answer though!! Haha